# applying live jquery events to iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to apply live click event to dynamically added element to an editable iframe.

```
$('#iframeView').contents().find('*').on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    selectItemElement($(this));
});
```

This works that it applies the events to elements in the iframe, but if i add new elements to the iframe they no longer get the on click event. So it's not applying live events.

any idea how to get this working?

Comment: `$('#iframeView').contents().find('body').on("click", '*', function(e) {...});` For hover, delegate `mouseenter mouseleave` events

Comment: the hover event i know how to do. Right now I can't figure out why click event is not being applied to new dynamic elements i'm adding to the iframe.

Comment: @RichardTorcato Because you aren't delegating click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delegate your events, meaning adding the events to a static container. The iFrame `document` will make a good static container, which is what using `.contents()` will get you.

If the event's target element matches your selector (`.on()`s second parameter), the function will be invoked.

```
$('#iframeView').contents().on("click",  '*', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    selectItemElement($(this));
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/usm2hvce/)

Comment: @RichardTorcato Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) you can use :

```
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

For e.g. :

```
$('#iframeView').contents().on("click",'*',function (e) {
 //Your code here 
});
```